# Regular Expression using `expl3`

Tags: expl3, l3regex

Can anyone explain these regular expressions using `expl3` and how those works?

```
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(ai) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(au) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-([āiueoīū]{1}) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(rr) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(r) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { \-([āiueoīū]{1}) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
```

Especially the last one. I could not figure out this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last line should replace `-ā` by `ā`, `-i` by `i`, `-u` by `u` and so on.

To break it up:

- `\-` represents the character `-`.
- Next, everything wrapped in parenthesis `(...)` is the part of the string that should be use for the replacement.
- Then follows a group wrapped in square brackets `[...]`, which essentially means "one of these".
- Following a repetition marker `{1}` meaning the character or group before "exactly once".
- As for the replacement, `\1` selects the first selection of the string, that is, the first part wrapped in parenthesis `(...)`, which is `[āiueoīū]{1}` in this case.

So, it means replace a `-` followed by one of `āiueoīū`, but only exactly one character of these, by this very character. Essentially, it removes the `-`.

See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) of the `l3regex` package which is currently included in the doc of the LaTeX3 interfaces (chapter 8).

Comment: `@Jasper Habicht` Thanks for your nice explanation. Can you give me an example explaining this line? What is the function of first `a` before \ in this line? `\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-([āiueoīū]{1}) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl`

Comment: `a` is just the letter `a`. For example, the first line replaces `a-ai` by `ai`.

Comment: Got it. thanks a bunch.

Comment: `\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-([āiueoīū]{1}) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl` does the very same like the last line, except that it removes `a-` and not just `-`.